# Why can't I send email from Thunderbird using an office365 account?

Tags: thunderbird, office365, smtp

I have been struggling to set up Thunderbird to use an office365 account. Receiving was fine, as was managing my mailbox, but it simply refused to send, despite having all of the right settings:

```
smtp.office365.com
port 587
STARTTLS security
OAuth2 authentication
Correct email username (address) and password
```

The email simply does not send, asking me to keep trying a new password.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, the issue appears to be a bug in the configuration allowing Authenticated SMTP connections. Using the [admin portal](https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal), it was possible to tick, un-tick, re-tick and wait, on the `Users>Active Users><user>>Mail>Email Apps>Manage Email Apps>Authenticated SMTP` checkbox. (Note the first ticking of the box had no effect, the subsequent un-tick and re-tick was the key.) Thanks to ['Vincent'](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/user/VickBi) from the Mozilla Support pages - in particular [his answer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1307784) on 16/12/2020 at 9:28 AM.